# React Navigation 5 - createNativeStackNavigator with custom header

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-v5

I'm using React navigation 5 on react native application. I try to use NativeStackNavigator with custom header. With React navigation 4 it's worked but no with 5.

React navigation 4:

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

...

const _baseNavigationOptions = (props, icon, text) => {
    return ({
      headerTitle: () => <TitleComponent  {...props} config={someConfiguration}/>,
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#6084AD',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#FFF'
    });
  }

...
const ConsumptionStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Consumption: {
        screen: Consumption,
        navigationOptions: _baseNavigationOptions({name:'bars', type: 'font-awesome'}, 'My Consumptions')
    }
}
```

When i'm trying to do the same thing with reactNavigation 5, the headerTitle doens't work :

```
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

...

  return (
      <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Consumption"
        screenOptions={{
          headerTitleAlign: 'center'
        }}>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Consumption"
          component={ComsumptionComponent}
          options={{ header: (props) => _baseNavigationOptions(props, {name:'bars', type: 'font-awesome'}, 'My Consumption') }}
        />
...
```

the header display Consumption and not my custom component. If i try with headerRight instead of headerTitle, I have the same problem

Can you help me :)

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `navigationOptions` in the v4 code, but `header` in v5 code. You need to set `options`, not `header`:

```
options={(props) => _baseNavigationOptions(props, {name:'bars', type: 'font-awesome'}, 'My Consumption')}
```

Comment: That work only with createStackNavigator but not with the native, the application crash without stacktrace

Comment: . Help me with this if you get a chance. Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61606346/react-navigation-v5-pass-function-as-parameter-to-be-used-in-headerright-butto